# How to add a dependency to an Eclipse bundle in a Tycho build

Tags: eclipse, maven, p2, tycho

I want to include `org.eclipse.uml2.uml_4.0.0.v20120604-0919.jar` in a Maven module. I've set up the p2 repository

```
<repository>
    <id>juno</id>
    <layout>p2</layout>
    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno</url>
</repository>
```

and configured the Tycho build extension. Which `groupdId` and `artifactId` do I have to use so that Tycho will include `org.eclipse.uml2.uml_4.0.0.v20120604-0919.jar` as a dependency?

Comment: Are you using the packaging type `eclipse-plugin`? If yes, please include this in the question.

Comment: Actually it isn't clarified if this should be an eclipse plugin or some other component. Maybe this has to be embedded in a maven mojo. But currently I'm packaging this as an eclipse plugin and it works like you described in your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to use one of Tycho's packaging types for Tycho to work. So you for example could not use the packaging type `jar` with Tycho. However, you can add plain Maven goals individually in the POM, and this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tycho, you need to specify the dependencies of your plug-in in the OSGi manifest file (`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`). So for the given Eclipse plugin, you would write something like

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.uml2.uml
```

You cannot do the same through POM configuration.

The idea behind this is that Tycho follows the so-called *Manifest-first* approach. The primary configuration files for Tycho are the OSGi manifest and the other Eclipse PDE file formats (like feature.xml, *.product files, etc.).

Other tools, like the maven-bundle-plugin follow the *POM-first* approach of building OSGi bundles. For the maven-bundle-plugin, you'd need to specify the dependencies in the POM, and the manifest is generated accordingly.