# Code building - adding maven dependency to EclipseLink (ant+maven+Tycho)

Tags: java, maven, ant, eclipselink, tycho

I want to add the following dependency to `org.eclipse.persistence.core`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The first my naive attempt was to add it to `org.eclipse.persistence.core/pom.xml`. As expected it didn't work. After that following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12410482/5057736 I added to `org.eclipse.persistence.core/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to Require-Bundle setting:

```
Require-Bundle: (original), org.slf4j;bundle-version="1.7.21"
```

However, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.persistence.core 2.6.3.qualifier to bundle org.slf4j 1.7.21.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
```

Could anyone give exact answer how to add this dependency to this `org.eclipse.persistence.core` project because after two hours, reading a lot of posts I have no solution.

Comment: First is org.slf4j providing OSGi bundles? I'm not sure...I would check the MANIFEST.MF of the packages...furthermore you are requiring a build `org.slf4j` but who offers this bundle ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your answer. I've checked - this jar is OSGI bundle. This is the link in maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21 . I can't say more, because I don't know.

Comment: mvnrepository.com is **NOT** Maven Central. Maven Central is here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ The search engine is here: https://search.maven.org/

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok. This is the url  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/ The jar file (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar ) is also OSGi bundle.

Comment: So this means first that your bundle name is wrong, cause the bundle name in slf4j is named: `sl4fj.api`

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, I don't understand you. If you know solution, please give and answer and I will accept it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Bundle-SymbolicName` of the dependency in the `Require-Bundle:` header

In your case it should be:

```
Require-Bundle: (original), slf4j.api;bundle-version="1.7.21"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't answer because I didn't work with that problem. But now I am back. Your solution also gives the exception:     `[java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.persistence.core 2.6.3.qualifier to bundle slf4j.api 1.7.21.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
     [java]  at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)`